Error: Cannot find module './xhr-sync-worker.js' when using jsdom in AWS Lambda with serverless-esbuild
I'm trying to use jsdom in an AWS Lambda function, bundled with serverless-esbuild. However, I'm encountering the following error:
[WARNING] "./xhr-sync-worker.js" should be marked as external for use with "require.resolve" [require-resolve-not-external]

node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:31:57:
  31 │ const syncWorkerFile = require.resolve ? require.resolve("./xhr-sync-worker.js") : null;
     ╵                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✖ Error: Cannot find module './xhr-sync-worker.js'
  Require stack:

Here is my yml file:
service: service-name

custom:
  esbuild:
    bundle: true
    minify: false
    sourcemap: true
    target: 'node20'
    external:
      - './xhr-sync-worker.js'
    platform: 'node'
    concurrency: 10

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x

plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  getDailyPrices:
    handler: src/functions/getDailyPrices/handler.function

I've tried marking xhr-sync-worker.js as an external module, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this error and properly bundle jsdom for use in AWS Lambda with serverless-esbuild?

I was facing the same issue.
I am using cdk and I needed to add this to NodeJSFunction
handler = new lambdaNode.NodejsFunction(stack, `${HANDLER_ID}${handlerId}`, {
  ...,
  bundling: {
      externalModules: ['canvas'],
      nodeModules: ['jsdom'],
    },
})

you would need to translate this into Serverless.
Maybe this, BUT UNTESTED!!
custom:
  esbuild:
    ...
    external:                # Exclude specific modules from being bundled
      - 'canvas'             # Exclude 'canvas' just like in your TypeScript config
    nodeModules:             # Include specific modules in the bundle
      - 'jsdom'

